# Swift Package Auto Docs

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

what is the best docs auto generator out there for Swift Packages?
I’ve tried jazzy docs, it’s good, tho just wondering if there is any alternative.

Comment: I'm having issues with jazzy and gems on the M1: "missing compatible arch"